# Why does the Transform's Z not change for an object constrained to an object that does move along Z?

Tags: transforms, constraints, parent

I have a "motorbox" object (just a plain box for now) animated to move vertically.  A "rod" (long thin cylinder) near it has a Copy Location constraint to copy the Z coordinate.   When I scrub the Timeline cursor back and forth, while the rod is selected, the Z shown for the Transform ('N' key side panel) does not change, though I see the rod move up and down following the motorbox.  Why?  As I have read, the Transform shown is the full global position/orientation of the object in world coordinates.

Comment: Its because the object it-self is not moving in fact (ie its because of that constraint). You could move the object for example 1m away and the coordinate shows 1m no matter its still on place because the constraint "prohibit" any movement.

Comment: Not just the transform Z shown in the properties panel, but also in Python, rod.location.z is not showing the actual location of the rod.  I've trying rod.matrix_world * Vector((0,0,0)) next - should matrix_world tell the actual position and orientation?

Comment: Dunno on this one so please wait for some "python master"...